# Can we use public cert. for AWS Site-to-Site VPN Tunnel Authentication?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, x509certificate2

Since private CA cert. cost $400 per month, can we use the public cert. instead?

Can we use acm public ca to identify ipsec Site-to-Site vpn endpoints?

Is there any restriction/limitation and cons on using public cert.? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS restricts using public cert. for VPN authentication, enforces to use the private cert. only.